# How do I write this function without duplicating code, following the DRY principle

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, code-cleanup

I want to start improving my way of writing code without **duplicating it**, the famous clean code, I would like to start applying it to small functions that are already used.
How could I improve this code without replicating the **switch condition** or even **creating a class** and using the *polymorphism* as the functions are **super similar**

```js
/**
 * Wait for an element and type on it
 * @param {puppeteer.Page} page - Context page
 * @param {string} selector - Element selector (CSS, xpath)
 * @param {string} text - Text to be typed in the element
 * @param {string} waitType - Element type (CSS, xpath)
 */
const waitAndType = async (page, selector, text, waitType = 'selector') => {
  switch (waitType) {
    case 'selector':
      await page.waitForSelector(selector)
      break
  }
  await page.type(selector, text)
}
// ===========================================

/**
 * Wait for an element and click on it
 * @param {puppeteer.Page} page - Context page
 * @param {string} selector - Element selector (CSS, xpath)
 * @param {string} waitType - Element type (CSS, xpath)
 */
const waitAndClick = async (page, selector, waitType = 'selector') => {
  switch (waitType) {
    case 'selector':
      await page.waitForSelector(selector)
      break
    case 'xpath':
      await page.waitForXPath(selector)
      break
  }
  await page.click(selector)
}
// ===========================================

// ===========================================
module.exports = {
  waitAndType,
  waitAndClick,
}
// ===========================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass an extra parameter to your function something like `actionType`. It can have two or more possible values based on your needs (type and click).

You can rewrite your function as follows:

```
const waitAndPerformAction = async (page, selector, waitType = 'selector', actionType) => {
  switch (waitType) {
    case 'selector':
      await page.waitForSelector(selector)
      break
    case 'xpath':
      await page.waitForXPath(selector)
      break
  }
  if(actionType === 'type') {
    await page.type(selector)
  } else if(actionType === 'click`) {
     await page.click(selector)
  }
}
```

You can take it a little further and define your `action` in a separate file (maybe a constants file) where you can define all your action types to avoid any typos throughout your codebase.

Something like:

```
const ACTION_TYPES = {
  CLICK: 'click',
  TYPE: 'type',
 ....
}
```

And then pass `ACTION_TYPES.CLICK` or `ACTION_TYPES.TYPE` as an `argument` to your function and modify your `waitAndPerformAction` function.

```
const waitAndPerformAction = async (page, selector, waitType = 'selector', actionType) => {
  switch (waitType) {
    case 'selector':
      await page.waitForSelector(selector)
      break
    case 'xpath':
      await page.waitForXPath(selector)
      break
  }
 await page[ACTION_TYPES[actionType]]();
}
```

And, finally call your function as:

```
waitAndPerformAction(..other arguments, ACTION_TYPES.CLICK)
```

Comment: Great solution . Thanks for the reply Rohit.
Do you always need to use several else ifs? The SRP (Single Responsability Principle) can be applie in this function?

Comment: Please check the second part of the solution where you don't have to `if/else if`. You can also map your actionTypes to the function to be called. For example in your `ACTION_TYPES`, you can modify it as `CLICK: {  name: 'click', toCall: page.click  }`.

You can then do something like `await ACTION_TYPES[actionType].toCall()`

Comment: @EduardoCarvalho Please mark the answer as correct and upvote it if it helped you, might help future readers. Thanks :)